# Docker containers not communicating between each others using fastapi and requests module on windows

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, containers

I've two apps- app1 and app2. When I call app1 using fast API, it calls app2 through fast API and returns the response from app2 to app1. Then app1 returns the response it got from app2. Both apps are working fine without docker. When I containerized both apps using docker-compose, they can't communicate but both are running. But I can access both containers using their APIs. I have also tried turning off my firewall, still not working. I'm using docker desktop on windows 10. Can anyone tell me/give me the fix, please? I'm exhausted trying different fixes. Thanks in advance.

> > Here are my codes:

> > App1:

```
#App1
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile,File, Form
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import requests
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
 
 response = requests.get('http://localhost:81/')
 #f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:81/')
 return {"response from app2":response.text}
```

> > App1 Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /testset
COPY main.py .
COPY . .
RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn requests
```

> > App2:

```
#App2 

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def prediction_route():
 f=2*5
  
 return f
```

> > App2 Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY main.py .
COPY . .
RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn requests
```

> > docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  app1:
    container_name: App1_tx
    build: ./app1/
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/testset
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command: uvicorn app1.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
    depends_on:
      - app2
  
  app2:
    container_name: App2_rx
    build: ./app2/
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    command: uvicorn app2.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 81
```

> > The Error response i get:

```
  INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/testset']

INFO:     172.18.0.1:39980 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error

INFO:     172.18.0.1:39976 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found

INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload

INFO:     Started server process [8]

INFO:     Waiting for application startup.

INFO:     Application startup complete.

ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn

    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection

    raise err

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection

    sock.connect(sa)

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 1):

When you work with `docker-compose` services use their service name rather than `localhost`.

Thus, change your line in `app1` from:

```
response = requests.get('http://localhost:81/')
```

to:

```
response = requests.get('http://app2:81/')
```

Comment: thanks. It's working now

Comment: You can thank me by accepting this answer and upvote :)